# Rails controllers without a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

At first glance, I'm sure the title makes this sound like a question that's been asked a million times before... but it's not.

My application DOES use a database, but only SOME pieces of the application actually rely on the database being up and running.  I would like to ensure that pieces of the application that DON'T depend on the database can still function correctly if/when the database is down.

The trouble is... as soon as a Rails app realizes it's lost its database connection, NO part of the application (save for static content) works.  (i.e. the exception is thrown BEFORE the flow of execution ever reaches a controller that does not depend on the database- a controller which would do just fine if it were permitted to do it's thing.)

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for?  Any help is appreciated!

**Update:**

After some careful examination, I believe the question boils down to this:

Is there a means of using "lazy" database connection pooling/handling such that a database connection isn't checked out of the pool until it's absolutely needed?  If possible, this would allow requests that don't use the database at all to proceed even if/when the database is down.

Thoughts?

**Update 2:**

Adding a stack trace.  This shows control never makes it to the controller when a database connection is not available.  (The database is obviously down intentionally so I can test this.)

```
PG::Error
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:771:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:771:in `new'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:771:in `connect'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:493:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:456:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:427:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:364:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:363:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:273:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:272:in `connection'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:552:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:632:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2745032424595922925__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:78:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Rails reserves a connection to the db on each request. I'm sure there must be a way to turn that off (maybe a middleware somewhere?), but there may not be much on this. You could try writing those bits in A microframework like Sinatra instead of Rails (which you can then mount into your rails app)

Comment: I don't think Rails calls the DB if it does not need to. Is it because you are saving sessions in the DB ?

Comment: I would recommend you to get a detailed check of this topic: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#back-to-railties-lib-rails-all-rb. The next step is to play around ```config/application.rb``` config and its ```require "rails/all"``` directive. You could have a look how mongoid avoids immediate activerecord initialization: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#installation

Comment: Thanks for the discussion, everyone.  I should have mentioned I'm using Race 4.0.0.rc2.  oldergod, you're right to an extent, no call is made to the database unless needed, but digging into the code, I see that @cpuguy83 was right on the money.  A CONNECTION is reserved (checked out of the connection pool) for every request.  This all happens in middleware BEFORE my application code ever gets its hands on a request.  What I really need is some option for LAZY connection reservation.  I'll keep digging.  4pcbr, your insight was helpful as well.  I'm going to have to give it a closer look.

Comment: Typo correct in previous comment.  "Race 4.0.0.rcs" was meant to read "Rails 4.0.0.rc2."  Also, see update above.

Comment: I suppose you could use some custom middleware to filter DB errors, but the router comes last in the middleware so i wouldn't know how to figure out which controller will handle the request.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry i'm answering about Rails 3, but i hope it would help a bit.

I have the same problem in a bit different circumstances, so i dug in the stacktraces and rails code and found out how to fix it in two lines.

TL;DR:

```
# config/application.rb
# before your application declaration
ActiveRecord::Railtie.initializers.reject! { |i| i.name == 'active_record.set_reloader_hooks' }
# inside your application declaration
config.middleware.delete ActiveRecord::QueryCache
```

First, when rails boots, it calls `ActionDispatch::Reloader.prepare!` (once for production, every request for development). This method is like setup in unit tests, it resets many things, among others it clears connections from connection pool and clears schema cache, and the latter checks out a DB connection from the pool. So the first line deletes the initializer in `active_record/railtie` that adds that callback. Probably you would want to do that only for production environment, but this modification should be in `application.rb` or above to work.

Second, rails indeed checks out a DB connection on every request, but this is done in `ActiveRecord::QueryCache` middleware. I decided i can do without it. If you really need it, i think you can enable and reset the cache in `around_filter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can rescue from database errors in your controllers with

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid do |e|
  logger.info 'ActiveRecord error ignored in databaseless controller:'
  logger.info e.message
end
```

Rescuing from `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` will probably cover all those database exceptions you want to ignore, but you will have to figure that out yourself. [The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/StatementInvalid.html) states that `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` is thrown in the following case:

> Raised when SQL statement cannot be executed by the database (for
>   example, it’s often the case for MySQL when Ruby driver used is too
>   old).

Otherwise you could also rescue from the more generic superclass `ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError` but that will cover *all* Active Record errors and is probably not what you want.

*Edit*: This won't handle the case where you don't have a connection at all so it's essentially useless in your case. I'll still keep the answer here in case someone else should be looking for this.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that won't work.  I'm observing that Rails reserves a database connection (checks it out of the pool) long before the request is ever routed to a controller (it happens in middleware).  Whatever exception-handling is built into the controller will have no effect.  Note again, I'm using Rails 4, although I believe this was true for 3.2.x as well.

Comment: I added a stack trace to my original post so you can see what I mean.

Comment: According to the stack trace, he maybe has to rescue from `PG::Error` instead.

Answer (score 0):

what you probably want to do is something similar to the above.
create a parent controller that all of it's inherited controllers are those that don't need the db access. use `rescue_from` to grab those db errors (`StatementInvalid` in this example)

```
class DbDontCare < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid do |exception|
    # do some logging or whatever
  end
end
```

Next, add your protection needed controllers to this scope

```
class IHateDb < DbDontCare
end
```

and so on.

You may need to add multiple `rescue_from` definitions in your parent controller to handle **all** possible exceptions.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but please note in the stack trace that control never reaches the controller or ANY application code.  This exception is being thrown from within the framework very early in the request life cycle.

Comment: From what i have been reading so far there is no real way of doing so for part of your app, you can remove active record completely but this won't help you. have you thought of breaking it into 2 different applications and interact via a RESTful interface?

Comment: That's not a very convenient solution to the problem, unfortunately.  If I break it into two applications, how then do I share templates, helpers, etc.?  This is logically ONE application.

Comment: Rails engines. same gem used in different projects